# The Events Calendar date in WP Query Loop

Tags: the-events-calendar

I'm using WP 6.2 with [The Events Calendar](https://theeventscalendar.com/products/wordpress-events-calendar/). I'd like to use the Post Query Loop functionality in the block editor to display events. The problem I run into is the date displayed is the *publish date* of the event, not the *date of the event*.

Is anybody aware of a way to display the event date in the loop - short code, or some other method?

Thanks,
Matt